# CSS transition only on not active

Tags: css, css-transitions

I have a scenario where I need to immediately change the background colour on hover, and revert back immediately to the original colour on dehovering. This is simple enough with:

```
#el {
    background-color: black;
}
#el:hover {
    background-color: gray;
}
```

However, I'm having an issue where I also need to immediately change the background colour on active, but to use a transition when active is released.

```
#el:active {
    background-color: green;
}

#el:hover:deactivate { /*does not exist*/
    background-color: gray;
    transition: background-color 1s ease;
}

#el:deactivate { /*does not exist either*/
    background-color: black;
    transition: background-color 1s ease;
}
```

I can't do this by setting #el:hover because then the hover entry also gets animated and I can't do this on #el itself because then dehovering also gets animated.

Is there any way to do this using pure CSS and without JS?

Comment: can you show us your html

Comment: Here is a jsfiddle of the scenario https://jsfiddle.net/ewtmc6kg/

Comment: Don’t think that is possible in CSS. You want the entering of one state (the “normal” one) to be treated two different ways, depending on which state it is entered _from_ – but there is no way to make that distinction in CSS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simulate this using a pseudo element and you will be able to manage two different things. The hover will change the background and the active state will change the pseudo-element:

```css
#el {
  color: white;
  background-color: black;
  border: 1px solid white;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  position:relative;
  z-index:0;
}
#el:before {
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  z-index:-1;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  bottom:0;
  background:transparent;
  transition:1s;
}

#el:hover {
  background-color: gray;
}

#el:active::before {
  background: green;
  transition: 0s;
}
```

```html
<div id="el">
  CONTENT HERE
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `:not(:active)`

```css
#el:active {
    background-color: green;
}

#el:not(:active):hover {
    background-color: gray;
    transition: background-color 1s ease;
}

#el:not(:active) {
    background-color: black;
    transition: background-color 1s ease;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" id="el">active</a>
```

Comment: that what you mean?

Comment: In theory, yes, but in practice, no, because #el:not(:active):hover is the same as #el:hover which results in an entry transition when you hover. Have added a jsfiddle to your comment on my question

Comment: I think you must use js or Jquery